# How can I find out why nothing happens when I click Commit in PyCharm?

Tags: git, pycharm

I have just edited a file in PyCharm (3.0 CE) and selected "Git / Commit File..." to bring up the "Commit Changes" dialog. After entering a comment, I click the "Commit" button. Nothing happens (no commit, no error message, no other feedback).

From the command line, I ran `git status` and `git status -uno` and got the same output both times:

```
# On branch trunk-new-feature
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 9 commits.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   ViewModel.py
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

From the command line, I ran `git commit ViewModel.py` instead. I was prompted for a comment and the change was committed as expected.

How can I find out why this didn't work in PyCharm?

Comment: I don't know PyCharm, but as a daily IntelliJ IDEA user, I imagine the Git plugin is the same. You should have a `Version Control` view at the bottom. It display Git command ran by the IDE, and errors if any.

Comment: @GuillaumeDarmont good idea! I can confirm that when I click "Commit" nothing happens in the `Version Control` view ... on other files that do commit, the appropriate git commands are logged

Comment: You should first add the file to the staging area and then commit all the changes. For example from command line if you execute git add . and then git commit -m "Added viewmodel.py" it will do the trick.